# add item to array if it doesn't exist mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm running a simple application with `mongoDB` + `nodejs`, I'm trying to achieve the following:

The **unit** belongs to a **company**, the **classroom** belongs to a **unit** and the **user** belongs to a **classroom**.

In certain moment, I want to add the user to another unit or/and classroom, then he'll belong to 2 or more units/classrooms.

My form will sent only one unit/classroom per time, in this case, I want to add it to the user model `unit:[string]` and `classroom:[string]` only if he doesn't previously belong to it. So I need to check if the arrays already have the sent data, if don't, add to it.

Mongo has the `$addToSet` property, and the `$ne` to do it, but I can't seem to make it work.

**Here's my code:**

```
User.findById(req.body._id)
    .select("-__v")
    .exec((err: Error, user: any) => {
            if (err) {
                // display error
            }
            if (!user) {
                // display error
            }
            user.update({
                unit: {
                    $ne: user.unit
                },
                classroom: {
                    $ne: user.classroom
                }
            }, {
                $addToSet: {
                    unit: req.body.unit,
                    classroom: req.body.classroom
                }
            }).exec((err: Error) => {
                if (err) {
                    // Display error
                }

                res.status(200).json({
                    status: "OK",
                    response: response,
                })
                return
            })
```

[image]

It belongs to "Academy one" and the classroom id reference, I will add him to another unit like "Academy 2" and add another classroom reference, but if I add him to another classroom of "Academy One", I don't want a duplicate item in it's unit array.

When I post the following through `postman`, it gives me the error:

```
{
"_id":"5d8ba151248ecb4df8803657", // user id
"unit":"Test", // another unit
"classroom":"5d8a709f44f55e4a785e2c50" // another classroom
}
```

**Response:**

> {
>       "status": "NOK",
>       "response": "Cast to [string] failed for value \"[{\"$ne\":[\"Academy One\"]}]\" at path \"unit\"" }

What am I missing?

Comment: See what error message says `"Cast to [string] failed for value \"[{\"$ne\":[\"Academy One\"]}]\" at path \"unit\""`

Comment: It falls on the `user.Update(..).exec((error:Error) => if (err){//cast error here}` block

Comment: How does your schema look like?

Comment: Do you now that `$addToSet` works for array field?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I didn't needed the `$ne` operator, I just needed to use the `$addToSet` directly

```
user.updateOne({
  $addToSet: { unit: req.body.unit, classroom: req.body.classroom }
}).exec((err: Error) => {
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$nin` instead of `$ne`, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

```
unit: {$nin: [user.unit]}
```

Comment: `$nin` with a single element and `$ne` are equivalent